# SwiftUI Combine observing updates

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a SwiftUI Form with a backing ViewModel. I wish to enable a Save button when the ViewModel changed. I have the following code:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var didUpdate = false
    @Published var name = "Qui-Gon Jinn"
    @Published var color = "green"
    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {
        self.name.publisher.combineLatest(self.color.publisher)
            .sink { _ in
                NSLog("Here")
                self.didUpdate = true
            }
            .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Toggle(isOn: self.$viewModel.didUpdate) {
                    Text("Did update:")
                }
                TextField("Enter name", text: self.$viewModel.name)
                TextField("Lightsaber color", text: self.$viewModel.color)
            }
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                Button("Save") { NSLog("Saving!") }
                    .disabled(!self.viewModel.didUpdate)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

There are two problems with this code.

First problem is that upon instantiation of the ViewModel, the log will show "Here", and thus set `didUpdate` to true. The second problem is that when the user changes the viewmodel via the textfields, it doesn't actually fire the publishers.

How should these problems be fixed?

(I've thought of adding `didSet{}` to each property in the ViewModel but that is very ugly when there are lots of properties. I've also thought of adding modifiers to the textfields, but I really prefer putting this code in the ViewModel, because a network update could also change the ViewModel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do what you want, however this option might not be what you want in the future. But what it all comes down to is the *mutability* of state.

First of all, you seem to confuse the `Model` with the `ViewModel`. In your case, the model should be something like this:

```swift
struct Model: Equatable {
    var name = "Qui-Gon Jinn"
    var color = "green"
}
```

Note that your model is `Equatable`. In swift, the default implementation that will be synthesized for you simply checks if all elements are equal to one another, i.e. the default implementation looks something like this:

```swift
static func ==(lhs: Model, rhs: Model) -> Bool {
    lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.color == rhs.color
}
```

We can use this behavior to get the desired result:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var original: Model
    @State var updated: Model
    
    init(original: Model) {
        self.original = original
        self.updated = original
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    TextField("Enter name", text: $updated.name)
                    TextField("Lightsaber color", text: $updated.color)
                }
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing:
                    Button("Save") { NSLog("Saving!") }
                        .disabled(original == updated)
                )
            }
        }
}
```

You can now simply pass an old (or new) model to your `ContentView`. Whenever the model is different from the original one, the save-button will be enabled and when it's the same, save is disabled. **Important**: This neat way of writing your model is only possible, when you use a `struct` as your model since they have value-semantics. It is also for this reason that `structs` are preferred over classes when modeling your task.

Now if you insist on using your `ViewModel` (for example because the conformance to `Equatable` is not possible or inefficient), you can do something similar. First, however, notice that this line

```swift
name.publisher
```

Is a publisher on the *name* (which would be of type `Publishers.Sequence<String, Never>`), not the `@Published` value (which is actually of type `Published<String>.Publisher`)
The former publishes every Character of the String, i.e. this

```swift
let name = "Qui-Gon Jinn"

let cancel = name.publisher.print().sink { _ in }
```

prints

```
Q
u
i
-
...
```

What you actually want is the *projected value* of the name, which already is a publisher i.e.

```
$name.dropFirst().sink { _ in
    NSLog("Here")
    self.didUpdate = true
}
```

Note that you need to drop the first value since the model immediately publishes after subscribing. You can also wrap all of this into the aforementioned model and call the publisher of the model (it will publish when any if it's properties changes).

Answer (score 2):

It is easier if you use a **struct** to hold the From fields' properties.

```
struct Model {
    var name: String
    var color: String
}
```

Then, in `self.$model.sink { value in}` compare if the new value if the same as the old one or it has changed.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var didUpdate = false
    @Published var model: Model
    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []
    
    init() {
        self.model = Model(name: "Qui-Gon Jinn", color: "green")
        self.$model.sink { value in
            
            guard !(value.name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty || value.color.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty) else {
                self.didUpdate = false
                return
            }

            if value.name != self.model.name {
                NSLog("name did chanage")
                self.didUpdate = true
            }
            
            if value.color != self.model.color {
                NSLog("Color did change")
                self.didUpdate = true
            }
            
        }
        .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }
    
    deinit {
        self.cancellables.removeAll()
    }
}
```

#### All Code

```
struct Model {
    var name: String
    var color: String
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var didUpdate = false
    @Published var model: Model
    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []
    
    init() {
        self.model = Model(name: "Qui-Gon Jinn", color: "green")
        self.$model.sink { value in
            
            guard !(value.name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty || value.color.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty) else {
                self.didUpdate = false
                return
            }
           
            if value.name != self.model.name {
                NSLog("Here")
                self.didUpdate = true
            }
 
            if value.color != self.model.color {
                NSLog("Here")
                self.didUpdate = true
            }
           
        }
        .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }
    
    deinit {
        self.cancellables.removeAll()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Toggle(isOn: self.$viewModel.didUpdate) {
                    Text("Did update:")
                }
                TextField("Enter name", text: self.$viewModel.model.name)
                TextField("Lightsaber color", text: self.$viewModel.model.color)
            }
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                    Button("Save") { NSLog("Saving!") }
                    .disabled(!self.viewModel.didUpdate)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### 1

`.navigationBarItems` is deprecated. Use `.toolbar` instead.

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
         Button("Save") { NSLog("Saving!") }
          .disabled(!self.viewModel.didUpdate)
    }
}
```

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbaritems(leading:trailing:)
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(content:)-5w0tj

#### 2

If you have multiple models, confirm to the `Identifiable`, `Equatable` protocols.

```
struct Model: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    
    var name: String
    var color: String
}
```